# Matlab: how to remove extra y axis generated by 'axes'?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am now having trouble plotting something by matlab.

```
x1 = 1:2500;
y1 = 1:2500:2500^2;
y2 = 1:2400:2500*2400;

figure
subplot(2,2,1);

semilogy(x1, y1, '-', x1, y2, '-.');
set(gca,'xticklabel',{[]});

pp = subplot(2,2,2);
pospp = get(pp, 'Position');
ax3 = axes('Position',pospp);
ax4 = axes('Position',[0.7 0.7 0.1 0.1]);
axes(ax3);
semilogy(x1, y1, '-', x1, y2, '-.');
set(gca,'xticklabel',{[]});
axes(ax4);
semilogy(2000:2500, y1(2000:2500), '-', 2000:2500, y2(2000:2500), '-.');
set(ax3,'xticklabel',{[]});
set(ax4,'xticklabel',{[]});
```

[Here is the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDNSJ.png)

I am wondering how can I remove one y axis from the right subplot? The one with "0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0"? I only want to keep the log-scale one.

Thank you.

Comment: Turn off `YTickLabel` like you're turning off `XTickLabel`

Comment: Hello, I tried but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
ax3 = axes('Position',pospp);
```

you create an extra axes object. Remove this line and the axes will be gone. Use `pp` instead of `ax3`.